# How do I reassign a scanner-based value that was already entered? - Java

Tags: java, methods, input, console-application, java.util.scanner

Not seeing any posts that I was able to answer my question with, I will ask it myself. I am currently trying to figure out some programming and had the intent of making a simple program that would ask a user to input an integer. After entering whatever the user had entered, if it is a variable, it would then say so in a following line of output. If the user had not entered an integer, it would catch the error and ask the user to attempt to reenter their integer--this process repeating until an integer was entered and the program could terminate.

Generally having a very low level of experience with anything above really straight-forward programming and having it be successful, my code not only has more errors above the problem I am currently having, but I probably have errors I didn't even know were there.

I have tried quite a lot of different things, and that is where I have somewhat of an idea of what is going on with some other blocks, but here is where I am right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LauncherMain {

    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void setInputValue() {
        int userInput = reader.nextInt();
    }

    public static void tryInputValue(int userInput) {       //do I even need this parameter, it seems to not have any correlation with the userInput integer I defined above
        try {
            setInputValue();
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException userInput) {    //if the code is in the method it will accept using userInput, but then goes on about some duplicate variable
            System.out.println("That wasn't an integer!");      //I haven't really looked into it, but I also would like this to be a warning instead of basic output
            setInputValue();    //I don't think this is right either, would it have to call a tertiary method that calls the try again? ...but I have a (necessary) finally block
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Awesome, your value is now: " + userInput);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        tryInputValue(int userInput);   //Looks like I am also getting some sort of error down here, it has to do with not being able to be resolved to a variable
    }

}
```

Alright, so if you managed to survive reading through that probably very wrong code, the main problem I was getting was getting it so that the user would be able to reenter what would hopefully be an integer after failing the previous attempt. What I had before trying to add a block to do that would work, and additionally, not crash if what was entered was not an integer, because that catch block was there. The problem with that was that I was stuck with that falsely entered value and therefore could not use the variable: userInput as it was an input mismatch. So after attempting to add in something that would allow it to be reassigned, it started throwing some errors, I began changing stuff, and now I am getting errors in different places that I do not even understand.

If anyone is willing to help, thank you tons! And if you are willing, a description of just what everything is doing in the fix you provide would be incredibly useful! :)

Comment: You have an `int userInput` and an `InputMismatchException userInput` in the same scope which will also cause you some problems.  `finally` blocks run after completion of a `try` or a `catch`, which is not the way you appear to be trying to use it.  `try/catch/finally` is not a [Control Flow Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `int userInput = reader.nextInt();`, the `userInput` varable is only defined in the scope of the `setInputValue()` method, so currently there is no way for you to access the input after it was entered.

You could either make `userInput` an instance variable, or you could just return the value from the `setInputValue()` method.

The duplicate variable error that you're getting on `catch (java.util.InputMismatchException userInput) {` is because you already have `userInput` defined as the parameter in the `tryInputValue()` method.
Just name the exception something else, like `(java.util.InputMismatchException e)`

You will also need to add a loop in order to always read input inside a try/catch block, otherwise you will not catch the exception if the input was invalid.

Here is one way you could go with fixing the errors and getting it working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LauncherMain {

    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    //int return value
    public static int setInputValue() {
        int userInput = reader.nextInt();
        return userInput; //return the value entered
    }

    //use int return value to access value in main
    public static int tryInputValue() {
        int userInput = 0; //initialize the variable to store input      
        boolean valid = false; //boolean to enable looping until valid input is entered
        while (valid == false){      
          try {
            userInput  = setInputValue(); //get return value
            valid = true;  //set valid to true if no exception thrown
          }
          catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {    //remove duplicate            
            System.out.println("That wasn't an integer!");                  

          }
          finally {
           //nothing needed here
          }
        }

        System.out.println("Awesome, your value is now: " + userInput); //this will work now, since userInput is in scope

        return userInput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        int n = tryInputValue();   //no parameter, but get the return value 

        System.out.println(n);   //you now have access to the number the user entered
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You provided a great description of what was wrong and, even more so, what means I have to take to fix it. This will totally help me with understanding the usage of instances!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in "int userInput" to the method, this is incorrect syntax. You need to pass in a value rather than a declaration. So for example:

```
int ui = 0;
tryInputValue(ui);
```

so if you want to pass in the value that the user types, you need to scan their input before calling tryInputValue. A simple way to test if the user typed an integer is to use Integer.partInt(String) here is the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

You should probably also have a do{...}while(); loop so that you continue prompting the user for input until it's formatted correctly.